# Ruby : trying to install rubyXL gem from file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, rubyxl

I am just starting with Ruby on Rails and need to use the RubyXL gem (https://github.com/gilt/rubyXL).  I was told by one of the other devs to use bundle install.  I cannot seem to get the syntax correct however, if I run "bundle install ./rubyXL-1.2.10.gem" I get ""install" was called incorrectly. Call as "bundle install".".  How do I use bund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need bundler you can add

`gem 'rubyXL', :path => '_path_to_file_'`
to your `Gemfile`

Comment: Thank you, I did this and it installed OK.  I went to refresh my Rails app but now it's showing the "Ruby (Rack) application could not be started" message with Error message:
    git://github.com/Goin/dm-migrations.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError

Comment: How are you using dm-migrations in your Gemfile?  Also look at your Gemfile.lock to check what dependency is requiring it, if your app is not requiring it directly. If its your app I would suggest using the latest released gem like `gem "dm-migrations", "~> 1.2.0"`

Answer (score 1):

You want `gem install ./rubyXL-1.2.10.gem`.